# SQL Unable to Concatenate

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2008-r2, concatenation

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and am trying to run the following command:

```
SELECT CustCity AS City, Concat(CustLastName, \', \', CustFirstName) AS Customer
FROM Customers
ORDER BY CustCity, Customer
```

The error message I am receiving is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ', \'.

As far as I have learnt, this is how `Concat` should work so I don't understand why this is not working.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `CONCAT` is a **NEW** function in SQL Server **2012** and doesn't exist in earlier versions

Comment: Also why do you have `, \'` instead of `, '\'`?

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:-

```
SELECT CustCity AS City, CustLastName + '\' + CustFirstName AS Customer
FROM Customers
ORDER BY CustCity, Customer
```

CONCAT function doesnot exist in SQL SERVER 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
SELECT CustCity AS City, CustLastName + '\' + CustFirstName AS Customer
FROM Customers
ORDER BY CustCity, Customer
```

Answer (score 1):

`CONCAT()` is not a function of SQL Server 2008.  If you want to concatenate the data in sql server, you should use the [`+` sign](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

```
SELECT CustCity AS City, CustLastName + ', ' + CustFirstName AS Customer
FROM Customers
ORDER BY CustCity, Customer;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d49b/1). If you want to include the `\`, then you can use:

```
SELECT CustCity AS City, CustLastName + ' \ ' + CustFirstName AS Customer
FROM Customers
ORDER BY CustCity, Customer
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d49b/5)

Answer (score 0):

Fairly certain your single quote `'` is causing the problem. Problem is CONCAT only exists in SQL 2012 not 2008.

If you were using SQL 2012, the proper syntax would be.

```
Concat(CustLastName, '\', CustFirstName) AS Customer
```

Comment: **CONCAT function doesnot exist in SQL SERVER 2008.**

Comment: My bad. Updated the answer to reflect that it would work in 2012.

Comment: @RahulTripathi As Jack stated; it only exists in 2012 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx